# LLVM/Clang 3.1 & libc++

Tags: 12.04, compiler

Has anybody built and setup an Ubuntu Precise PPA for LLVM/Clang 3.1? A bonus would be to have a recent version of libc++ integrated into it aswell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I uploaded debian/sid packages of llvm-3.1 and clang-3.1 to [my ppa](https://launchpad.net/~eudoxos/+archive/llvm-3.1).

Comment: +1, This is great, however, is it possible to add a fixed version of `libstdc++-4.7` to it (see notes [here](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html))? As `<chrono>` is currently [broken](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=12893).

Comment: That is a separate package and I don't have patch for `libstdc++-4.6`, which is what ubuntu 12.04 ships. Maybe you can patch your installed header, the pathc for 4.7 is a one-liner.

Comment: Will try it that way then, thank you for the great ppa.

Comment: @eudoxos "the patch for 4.7 is a one-liner" — Which line?

Comment: Found one 1-line patch: http://clang.llvm.org/libstdc++4.7-clang11.patch (see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=666539 for discussion) but it doesn't fix the issue with `<chrono>` that I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Just found an article about installing Clang and libc++ from sources on Ubuntu 12.04.1 and 12.10. The author uses the latest versions for both Clang and libc++. Hope this will be useful:

http://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/01/17/building-clang-libcpp-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: This answer isn't very useful for two reasons: 1. The OP asked for a PPA, not compiling himself. 2. Providing a link to some volatile web content is not enough effort for an answer.